# How can I replace the vowels of a word with underscores in python?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner learning the python language and I'm stumped on how take the vowels of a word and replacing them with an underscore.

So far this is what I have come up with and it just doesn't work

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
new_word = ""
vowels = "aeiouy"


for letter in word:
    if letter != vowels:
        new_word += word
    else:
       new_word += "_"
       print(new_word)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `string.translate` and `maketrans`.

```
from string import maketrans

vowels = "aeiouy"
t = "______"
st = "trying this string"
tran = maketrans(vowels, t)

print st.translate(tran)
# Gives tr__ng th_s str_ng
```

You may also want to check uppercases.

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex

```
import re
print(re.sub("[aeiouAEIOU]", "_", "abc"))    # prints _bc
```

Answer (score 1):

Make vowels an array with each element it's own letter.

Then do

```
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        letter = "_"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists can be used to easily build words, and with `.join()` you can combine the list items into a single string.

```
word = 'pizza'
vowels = "aeiouy"
new_word = []
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        new_word.append('_')
    else:
        new_word.append(letter)
print(''.join(new_word))
```

Here's the same thing in a generator expression:

```
word = 'pizza'
vowels = "aeiouy"
new_word = ''.join(c if c not in vowels else '_' for c in word)
print(new_word)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer why your approach didn't work.

```
if letter != vowels:
```

Does not do what you are thinking. It actually compares the letter against a full string `"aeiouy"`. It will always be unequal (e.g. `"a" != "aeiouy"` is True and so is any other letter).

More likely what you mean was

```
if letter in vowels:
```

Which under the hood will iterate over `vowels` and compare each character to `letter`, returning `True` if any of the letters match.

The second mistake is here

```
new_word += word
```

You are adding the original word to the new word rather than the letter you just checked. So make that

```
new_word += letter
```

The third thing to note is that your logic is the reverse of what you intended. You wanted to replace vowels with `_` but your if statement allows vowels into the new word and replaces consonants with the underscore. So if you reverse your if and else clauses.

All up you end up with

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
new_word = ""
vowels = "aeiouy"

for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        new_word += '_'
    else:
       new_word += letter

print(new_word)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was so helpful.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept (and upvote) this or any of the other answers, whichever you feel helped you most.

Comment: You've got my upvote for also taking the time to explain what went wrong. ..EDIT: Only just saw the date, but anyway you deserved the vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension and setting `vowels` as a `set` object (this is really only valuable for speeding up performance if you have a large list of words over which you're iterating):

```
>>> vowels = set("aeiouy")
>>> word = 'ampersand'
>>> new_word = "".join([letter if letter not in vowels else "_" for letter in word])
>>> print(new_word)
_mp_rs_nd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3, use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to build a string translation table:

```
vowels = "aeiouy"
vowels += vowels.upper()
tr = str.maketrans(vowels, '_' * len(vowels))

print('Yo, this is a wacky phrase!'.translate(tr))
```

Shows: `__, th_s _s _ w_ck_ phr_s_!`

Answer (score 0):

**DRAX: I'll do you even better!**

```
def replace_vowels(word):
        vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
        for x in (word.lower()):
                if x in vowels:
                        word = word.replace(x, "_")
        print(word) 

replace_vowels('Stackoverflow')
```

> Output

```
St_ck_v_rfl_w
```